# Best way to implement Material expandable input chip in flutter?

Tags: flutter, material-design

I'm trying to figure out a way to implement the "expandable" behaviour illustrated in https://material.io/design/components/chips.html#input-chips.

I've dismissed using a combination of Stack+Positioned & AnimatedSwitcher, since this would require inserting the input chip at the scaffold's top level, when it's initial position should rather be determined exclusively by it's actual parent (e.g. a wrapping row). Everything else seems to contradict flutter's "overflow is evil" rule, however.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unaware of the [Overlay widget](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Overlay-class.html)'s existence and have built my implementation based on that.

Comment: Can you share your implementation?

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with exactly?